# Databinding the DataGrid column header in code

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

How do I databind a [WPF Toolkit DataGrid](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx) column header value *in code* (not XAML)?

```
DataGridColumn fooColumn =  new DataGridTextColumn 
{
  Header = "Foo",
  Binding = new Binding {Path = new PropertyPath("BindingPath"), 
                         Mode = BindingMode.OneWay}
};
```

This databinds the content of the cells of the column. But how do I databind the header text ("Foo") itself (to, say, a string property on a viewmodel)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataGridColumn fooColumn =  new DataGridTextColumn 
{
  Binding = new Binding {Path = new PropertyPath("BindingPath"), 
                         Mode = BindingMode.OneWay}
};

BindingOperations.SetBinding(fooColumn, DataGridColumn.HeaderProperty, new Binding("Foo") { Source = yourViewModel} );
```