# How do I databind DataGridColumn.SortDirection in WPF, using XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

This is related to [Databinding the DataGrid column header in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312613/databinding-the-datagrid-column-header-in-code) but it asks the opposite question: "How do I do it in XAML?", not "How do I do it in code?"

I've constructed this MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" Sorting="DataGrid_Sorting" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" SortDirection="{Binding SortDirection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Click Me" x:Name="column"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and this MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ListSortDirection? _sortDirection;
    public ListSortDirection? SortDirection
    {
        get => _sortDirection;
        set
        {
            // I expect this message box to appear, but it doesn't.
            MessageBox.Show($"Setting sort direction to {value?.ToString() ?? "null"}");
            _sortDirection = value;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> ItemsSource { get; } = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.Select(x => new { Value = x }).ToList();

    public MainWindow() => InitializeComponent();

    private void DataGrid_Sorting(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
        => MessageBox.Show($"Sorting grid.\nColumn sort direction was {column.SortDirection?.ToString() ?? "null"}.");
}
```

The binding works as expected for `DataGrid.ItemsSource`, but no binding I've constructed works for `DataGridColumn.SortDirection`. When clicking the column header ("Click Me"), I expect to see both message boxes, but only one appears.

---

I can put `BindingOperations.SetBinding(column, DataGridColumn.SortDirectionProperty, new Binding(nameof(SortDirection)) { Source = this, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });` in the constructor to set up the binding as expected, but I've been brought up to believe that bindings should be constructed in XAML, not in code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A `DataGridColumn` is not a visual element and doesn't inherit any `DataContext`. You could implement a binding proxy to work around this. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22074985/7252182) answer and [this](https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) blog post for examples and more information.

> but I've been brought up to believe that bindings should be constructed in XAML, not in code.

As a side note, there is nothing wrong with setting up bindings programmatically. It doesn't break the MVVM design pattern. XAML is a *markup* language. You can implement an entire view programmatically if you really want to. Trying to do *everything* in XAML just for the sake of it is generally considered an anti-pattern. A (fairly) complex view usually needs code.

Comment: I did end up going with a code-based binding, rather than using the `Freezable` workarounds.